# Struts 2 in RAD

Tags: struts2, ibm-rad-7.5

Does Struts2 work on RAD 7.5.5 ?

I am creating a sample dynamic web project in RAD, and my JSP pages are getting called, but the Action classes are not invoked.

I am getting the below error:

```
Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /hello
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. Also, switch devMode to true, increase logging to DEBUG level, check your startup logs, and include your configuration. There are also a few WS-specific S2 issues, but my understanding was that they have been resolved in WS7+.

Comment: What a strange file name. Could you post the real path.

Answer (score 0):

**It supports Struts2**, as every other 3rd party technology, but it does not provide any specific tooling as for Struts 1.3.

> Rational Application Developer 7.5 and 8.0 do not provide any specific
>   tooling for Struts 2.x (such as it does for Struts 1.x).
>
> For example, you will need to obtain the Struts 2.x runtime files from
>   the Struts Web site yourself and manually add them to (and configure
>   them within) a Dynamic Web project in which you intend to use Struts
>   2.x.
>
> Note: A Struts 2.x application is treated as a standard Dynamic Web
>   project.
>
> FROM: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21327401

You can verify your installation with the **[Introduction to Struts 2.x using RAD 7.5](http://www.webagesolutions.com/setupguides/WA1926SetupGuide.pdf)** guide (that has nothing to do with S2, despite the title),

and download and run a [**template project from here**](http://blog.webagesolutions.com/archives/360) , to start from something running.

By the way your seems an configuration error, check your cfg from zero, or use the template.